# Taking n-th root

Tags: rust, nth-root

What is the best way to take the n-th root of an arbitrary number in rust?
The num crate for example only allows to take n-th principal roots of integer types, i.e., floor'ed or ceil'ed values... How to best closely approximate the actual value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Mathematically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root), n<sup>th</sup> root is actually `1 / n` power to the number.

You can use `f64::powf(num, 1.0 / nth)` to calculate such roots.

```rust
fn main(){
    println!("{:?}", f64::powf(100.0, 1.0 / 3.0));
    // same as cbrt(100), cube root of 100
    // general formula would be
    // f64::powf(number, 1.0 / power)
}
```

You can use `f32::powf` also, there's no problem with it.

Comment: ah yes of course. thanks for the hint :) wasn't aware you could simply pass the reciprocal of n into that as the exponent

Comment: @D3PSI Not a problem